# Cannot get a result from one function only

Tags: javascript, html

In my Web application, I am trying to get an answer from only one function if the user wishes to run only one selection rather than two. This means that the code runs instantly with every function. At the end of both functions I have implemented this code so even if the user choose only one function to execute will still run but this is not happening.  "document.getElementById("ansCAL").innerHTML = "
Total amount " + (total + total1);

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
function populate(select1, select2)
{
    var Brand1 = document.getElementById(select1);
    var Brand2 = document.getElementById(select2);
    Brand2.innerHTML = "";
    if(Brand1.value == "Chevy")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","1000|Camaro","2000|Corvette","3000|Impala"];//The | means a blank space, camaro is the label, Camaro is the value, ex. value 1000 and corvette is the label
    }
    else if(Brand1.value == "Dodge")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","4000|Avanger","5000|Challengere","6000|Charger"];
    }
    else if(Brand1.value == "Ford")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","7000|Mustang","8000|Shelby","focus|Focus"];
    }
    for(var option in optionArray)//the options within the optionArray
    {
        var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");//in tha variable pair is stored both value and label
        var newOption = document.createElement("option");// option in the bracket is used to create new options or you can insert divs paragraph etc
        newOption.value = pair[0];//pair 0 gives the value
        newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];//pair 1 gives the label
        Brand2.options.add(newOption);
    }
}
//second function
function calculate() {
    var Brand1 = 0;
    var Brand2 = 0;
    Brand1 = document.getElementById('slct1').value;
    Brand2 = document.getElementById('slct2').value;
    multi=document.getElementById('amount').value;
    total=parseInt(Brand2)*multi;
    document.getElementById('answer').value=total;
    document.getElementById("ansCAL").innerHTML = "<br>Total amount " + (total + total1);
}
//second Main function
function populate1(Select1a, Select2a)
    {
        var Brand1a = document.getElementById(Select1a);
        var Brand2a = document.getElementById(Select2a);
        Brand2a.innerHTML = "";
        if(Brand1a.value == "Chevy")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","1000|Camaro","2000|Corvette","3000|Impala"];//The | means a blank space, camaro is the label, Camaro is the value, ex. value 1000 and corvette is the label
    }
    else if(Brand1a.value == "Dodge")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","4000|Avanger","5000|Challengere","6000|Charger"];
    }
    else if(Brand1a.value == "Ford")
    {
        var optionArray = ["|","7000|Mustang","8000|Shelby","focus|Focus"];
    }
        for(var option in optionArray)//the options within the optionArray
        {
            var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");//in tha variable pair is stored both value and label
            var newOption = document.createElement("option");// option in the bracket is used to create new options or you can insert divs paragraph etc
            newOption.value = pair[0];//pair 0 gives the value
            newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];//pair 1 gives the label
            Brand2a.options.add(newOption);
        }
    }
//second function
function calculate1() {
    var Brand1a = 0;
    var Brand2a = 0;
    Brand1a = document.getElementById('slct1a').value;
    Brand2a = document.getElementById('slct2a').value;
    multi=document.getElementById('amount1').value;/*to change accordingly amount1*/
    total1=parseInt(((Brand2a)*multi)/100);
    document.getElementById('answer1').value=total1;/*to change accordingly amount1*/
    document.getElementById("ansCAL").innerHTML = "<br>Total amount " + (total + total1);
}
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <form>
    Choose Your Car:
    <select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate('slct1','slct2')">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
        <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
        <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    </select>

    Choose Type of Car:
    <select id="slct2" name="slct2">

    </select>
    <label>&nbsp;Amount&nbsp;<input type="number" name="amount" id="amount" size="1" onkeyup="calculate()"/>    (g)&nbsp;</label>
    <label>&nbsp;Total&nbsp;<input type="number" name="answer" id="answer" size="1"/></label>   
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"/>
    <br><br><br>
    <hr>
    <br>
    </form>
    <!--Starts 2 selection-->
    <form>
        Choose Your Car:
    <select id="slct1a" name="slct1a" onchange="populate1('slct1a','slct2a')"><!--changed accordingly increased a after slct1a-->
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Chevy">Chevy</option>
        <option value="Dodge">Dodge</option>
        <option value="Ford">Ford</option>
    </select>

    Choose Type of Car:
    <select id="slct2a" name="slct2a">

    </select>
    <label>&nbsp;Amount&nbsp;<input type="number" name="amount1" id="amount1" size="1" onkeyup="calculate1()"/>     (g)&nbsp;</label>       <!--changed accordingly increased 1 after calculate-->
    <label>&nbsp;Total&nbsp;<input type="number" name="answer1" id="answer1" size="1"/></label>   
    <input type="reset" name="Reset" value="Reset"/>
    <br><br><br>
    <p id="ansCAL"></p>
    </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: `function populate(s1,s2)
    {
        var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
        var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);` you think giving local variables the same name as the parameters of the surrounding function is a smart idea?

Comment: I am new to javascript. If you can help me I can learn from your code. That is why I have posted my code so I can learn from mistakes. I got that code from (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UliJeDbc4cw). He teaches javascript. If he is wrong than can help me out to the right direction?

Comment: I have fixed that by changing all variables.

Comment: Not trynna be general and subjective but why do you think watching youtube videos is a smart idea? I think reading good books and articles and practicing is a better idea.

Comment: I am learning on code academy website and w3schools but I cannot find the way to solve this problem and I am trying to do my best to get knowledge from everywhere but it is not always easy believe me. That is why I am asking for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function result() {
   document.getElementById('ansCAL').value = calculate() + calculate1();
}
```

This will add the above 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

I propose a simple construction so that you can guess from where the function call is made (first learning step ;) ):

```js
function populate(rawNumber)
{
  var sa1;
  var sa2;

  if (rawNumber === 1) {
    sa1 = document.getElementById('slct1');
    sa2 = document.getElementById('slct2');
  } else if (rawNumber === 2) {
    sa1 = document.getElementById('slct1a');
    sa2 = document.getElementById('slct2a');
  }
...
}
```

Call that code simply by calling `populate(1)` or `populate(2)`.

And do the same with `activate` but I guess you didn't finish yet to code that part anyway.

Even better way (second learning step ;) ):

```js
function populate()
{
  var sa1;
  var sa2;
  var source = event.target || event.srcElement;

  if (source.id === 'slct1') {
    sa1 = document.getElementById('slct1');
    sa2 = document.getElementById('slct2');
  } else if (source.id === 'slct1a') {
    sa1 = document.getElementById('slct1a');
    sa2 = document.getElementById('slct2a');
  }
}
```

Just call it with `populate()`, your code will know from where it comes anyway!

By the way, use a better naming strategy for your variables name; for example, use names lie `brand1`, `type1`, `amount1`, and `total1` for the first one, and so on for others. Don't use `s`, because we don't know what it means, and `slct` is too vague.

Comment: Thanks my friend. You are a good guy and understand that people like us that are still learning need help to understand better the codes.